# MongoDB on macOS: How do I resolve chown: data/db: No such file or directory

Tags: mongodb, macos, chown

I installed MongoDB via Homebrew and created the `/data/db` directory.

When I run `sudo chown -R id -un /data/db`. I get this error:

> chown: data/db: No such file or directory

I've tried all solutions I can find online and I see that the directory exists, but I am not sure what's going on. When I run `mongod` this is what I get:

> Solomons-MacBook-Pro:expense-tracker Solomon$ mongod
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-07T19:02:47.741-08:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire
> specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-07T19:02:47.747-08:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically
> disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify
> --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"} {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-07T19:02:47.748-08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",
> "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during
> NetworkInterface startup"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-07T19:02:47.748-08:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP
> FastOpen in use."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-07T19:02:47.754-08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",
> "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during
> NetworkInterface startup"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-07T19:02:47.756-08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered
> PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-07T19:02:47.756-08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered
> PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-07T19:02:47.756-08:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB
> starting","attr":{"pid":3449,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Solomons-MacBook-Pro.local"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-07T19:02:47.756-08:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build
> Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.3","gitVersion":"657fea5a61a74d7a79df7aff8e4bcf0bc742b748","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-07T19:02:47.756-08:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating
> System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"21.1.0"}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-07T19:02:47.756-08:00"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set
> by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-07T19:02:47.758-08:00"},"s":"E",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to
> unlink socket
> file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission
> denied"}} {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-07T19:02:47.758-08:00"},"s":"F",
> "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal
> assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":960}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-07T19:02:47.758-08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",
> "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after
> fassert() failure\n\n"}

Comment: What's the exact problem? It's saying that `/data/db` is not a file. And I think in most GNU/Linux distribution `/data` is not a standard directory. Please clarify your question and tell us what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

On your Mac, if you used Homebrew to install MongoDB, the data directory is created on installation. However, it is not `data/db`. Instead, on Intel Mac it is `/usr/local/var/mongodb` and on M1 Mac it is `/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb`.

To correctly install MongoDB using Homebrew (of course, check what's the latest version):

```
 brew tap mongodb/brew
 brew install mongodb-community@6.0
```

First, check that your MongoDB is running ok by listing the running services using `brew`:

```
brew services list
```

You should see something like:

```
Name              Status  User File
MongoDB-community started root
```

If not, try to stop, start or restart the service:

```
 brew services stop mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
 brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
 brew services restart mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
```

For further information about the possible problems, check the log file:

```
 tail $(brew --prefix)/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
```

More details in the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/).

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue today. Try the following commands in order :

**sudo mkdir -p /System/Volumes/Data/data/db**   --> This will create a new folder, as with the new Catalina OS, the root directory changed.

After this command, you will need to get write permissions.
**sudo chown -R `id -un` /System/Volumes/Data/data/db**

In order to finally open a mongo db connection, enter the following command:
**sudo mongod --dbpath /System/Volumes/Data/data/db**

---

For reference, use the following link: https://superuser.com/questions/1458974/macos-switched-root-mongodb-data-folder-to-system-ownership-and-it-cannot-be-cha

Answer (score 0):

After Catalina the root folder is no longer writable.
So I created a folder on Desktop called MongoDB, and inside here the tmp & data/db.

And now I run it like this:

```
mongod --unixSocketPrefix ~/Desktop/MongoDB/tmp --dbpath ~/Desktop/MongoDB/data/db
```